# continuous functions on two open subsets

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, continuity

> Let $f$ be continuous on open subset $U\subset R^n$, and continuous on open subset $V\subset R^n$. If $f$ agree on $U\cap V$. Show that $f$ is continuous on $U\cup V$.

How to prove this theorem using $\epsilon-\delta$? The problem comes when we consider $f$ at $x\in U\cap \partial V$. If $x\in U\cap V$, or $x\in U-\bar V$, or $x\in V-\bar U$, then it is easy....

Note. $f: E\to R$ is contiunous at $x$ if $\forall\ \epsilon>0,\exists\ \delta>0$, such that for all $x'\in B(x,\delta)\cap E$, $|f(x')-f(x)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy See the statements after the problem.

Comment: It would have been better to start with a continuous function $f$ on $U$ and a continuous function $g$ on $V$ such that $f=g$ on the  intersection. The present wording is very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f : U \cup V \to \mathbb R$ be a function such that $f \mid_U$ and $f \mid_V$ are continuous. We want to show that $f$ is continuous.

So consider $x \in U \cup V$ and $\epsilon > 0$.

Case 1. $x \in U$.

We know that there exists $\delta_U > 0$ such that $|f(x')-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x'\in B(x,\delta_U)\cap U$. Since $U$ is open, there exists $\delta' > 0$ such that $B(x,\delta')\subset U$. Define $\delta = \min(\delta_U, \delta')$. Then clearly $|f(x')-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x' \in B(x,\delta) \cap (U \cup V) = B(x,\delta) \subset B(x,\delta_U)\cap U$.

Case 2. $x \in V$.

This works eaxctly as in case 1.

Answer (score 0):

If $x \in U\cap \partial V$ then $x \in U$ so we can choose $\delta$ such that $B(x,\delta) \subseteq U$ and $|f(x')-f(x)| <\epsilon$ for all $x' \in B(x,\delta) \cap U (=B(x,\delta$)). Now apply the definition. $V$ (or $\partial V$) does not even come into the picture.